# Should I be testing files before or after Webpack bundles them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, automated-tests, gitlab-ci

**Background:** I'm working with an older codebase and one repository uses Webpack to compile some handlers for AWS lambda functions. There's no existing tests for these specific lambda functions but they're not deployed to production and exist only to simplify some of the automated testing in the backend. Recently, while updating the version of Node we're using, the Webpack deployment broke and it wasn't caught until tests in other repositories that depend on these lambdas were failing. Our code itself was still fine, but a Webpack config option had changed and as a result the bundled code's entry point changed.

I want to include some automated testing to prevent this from happening again, but I'm not sure where in the build process those tests should sit. If the tests are run against the handler code before it's compiled by Webpack, then this most recent issue would not have been caught. However, if we're testing the compiled code then it will be harder to spot the cause for any failures. It also means the automated tests in the CI/CD pipeline will be dependent on the `build` stage (unless these tests are run as part of the `build` stage itself, but I think this is bad practice).

**What's the standard approach for testing Webpack-created files? Should I avoid running unit tests against the bundled code and go for an integration test or two for sanity-checking purposes coupled with more thorough unit testing, or is unit testing Webpack-created files acceptable?**

A larger scale refactoring is probably not going to be a viable option, but if I'm missing a simpler refactor that would help then that would also be helpful advice.